# JavaFX: How to adjust/maximize Control/Region widths on resizing a window?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

When I resize a JavaFX window, I get the red highlighted spaces
[image]

at the bottom and right. I’ve tried a lot in the SceneBuilder to auto-maximize the “Bottom Left Control” by specifying a larger height & width alongside a “Pref Height” and “Pref Width” but nothing worked.

Of course I could register a resize listener that resizes the controls at runtime imperatively but that’s not really a nice solution. Is there a declarative way where this magic is done behind the scenes and where I have to merely set some flag to accomplish this?

Comment: What layout are you using?

Comment: @James_D I’m not sure what you mean but the top level pane is an “AnchorPane”.

Comment: That's probably a really bad choice if you want the child nodes to resize. `AnchorPane` is pretty much a static layout pane. It looks like a `GridPane` with appropriate `RowConstraints` and `ColumnConstraints` would be better suited to this layout. I recommend you read the [tutorial on layout panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102). There is also a good [presentation on JavaFX layout](https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/interface-layout-javafx-2-0) (need registration)

Comment: AnchorPane has static methods to anchor nodes to specific side. Try to use them.